# Layout Background partially transparent

Tags: android

I want to set a transparent background. Maybe 20% of gray
but i also want to have a small part of the background being completely transparent (a rectangle or a circle in the layout):

[image]

Is that possible? later i want the rectangle (or the circle) to be moveable and scaleable.

Comment: Do you intent to see the Android Launcher in the background?

Comment: No, in the background there will be another layout with an image. i dont want to see the android launcher.

Comment: ah i wanted to suggest you to apply this style http://stackoverflow.com/a/2700683/3080611 but now I see the problem you are encountering...

Comment: User background color as #AA000000

Comment: @Surender Kumar: No, that is not what i want. Read again :D

Comment: This is easily achievable with a custom drawable. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591405/how-to-create-a-crop-layer-for-a-moveable-image/28591953#28591953

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easily achievable with a custom drawable like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:innerRadius="0dp"
       android:shape="rectangle"
       android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
       android:useLevel="false">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <stroke
        android:width="125dp"
        android:color="#CC000000"/>
</shape>
```

When you overlay that drawable on top of an image the results would looks something like this:

[image]

By creating that drawable dynamically in code you can adjust it at runtime. For example:

```
ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
drawable.getPaint().setColor(0xCC000000);
drawable.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
drawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(dpToPixel(125.0f));
someView.setBackground(drawable);
```

You can influence the shape of the hole in the middle by combining multiple layers in a `LayerDrawable`.

You can also influence the general shape of the hole by setting the `android:shape` tag of the `<shape />` element in the custom drawable.

Comment: Its a good solution when you dont want to move the rectangle in the middle. but i later want to be able to move and scale the 100% transparent rectangular area.

Comment: You can move it, scale it, rotate it or whatever you want to do with it by moving, scaling or rotating the whole drawable.

Comment: And you can change the drawable dynamically at runtime by creating it programmatically.

Comment: hmmm.. i tired some things now but i really dont know how to implement the shapes programmatically.

Comment: I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for that and sorry my reply was onclear. I knew how to create a shape programmatically, what i dont know is how to set the with and the height of it dynamically to make it scaleable and also when i want to move the frame later, i dont know how to set left stroke other size than right stroke.

Comment: You know my goal later is to achiev a cropping mechanism for my images and i dont want to use libs because i hate to use code i dont understand and people always making things complicated.

Comment: oh its ok. i got another idea. your solution is perfect for that. i thank you. i will just create a frame like you showed and i will not make the frame move or scaleable. i will make the imageview move and scaleable. thank you

Comment: Is it possible to turn that transparent area into a square?

Comment: @XaverKapeller how can I make the center transparent area square?